# TextMate: using tmctags bundle, opens in new window!!! how do i open it as a tab?

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

I have this issue with textmate where it opens up a file in a new window, but not a tab.  thereby its harder to navigate and also disables me from using tcmtags on that new file.  Has anyone ever ran into this issue?  I suspected it was some type of setting that got messed up, but opening any other file traditionally with the point and click will open in a new tab.  So why does it screw up using tcmtags?

Thanks!
Tony

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem with the Latex bundle in a newly created project. The Latex bundle had a macro that was using the 'open' command.

Quitting and reopening TextMate solved it for me. Files now open in a new tab rather than new window.

Answer (score 0):

Only Projects have tabs in Textmate afaik. So create a new project e.g. by dropping a folder on the TextMate Icon in dock. The files in this folder will open in tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that my files are in a project.  It's the bundle that has the issue.  Jumping to a definition source in a different file opens the file in a new window as opposed to a new tab.  All the files are in the same project.

No one else I know has this issue.